# Color scheme in Haskell-Chart

Tags: haskell, charts

I use Haskell-Chart according to the example [example-1](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/wiki/example-1).Everything works fine. But I can`t get, how it is possible to change colors (backgound, axes, ...)? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the documentation?

I will only answer the part about background and leave the rest to you, as it shoud be possible to get all the information you seek in the docs, otherwise aks a new, more concrete question.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-1.8/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Layout.html for example provides the type `Layout x y` where you can set the background.